Solution to KVM and VNC no longer working after upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04.1 desktop
I upgraded my Ubuntu 22.04 desktop install to Ubuntu 24.04 and it seemed to go well. I have a working install. However, my workflow is broken and there doesn't seem to be a solution available. I have the following three problems:

I had been using barrier to share my keyboard, mouse, and clipboard
between my local Win11 machine (with physical keyboard and mouse) and
my Ubuntu 22.04 machine and my work Win11 laptop. The upgrade to
Ubuntu 24.04 broke barrier (and every other software KVM I could
find).
Also, I had been using X11vnc to share the Ubuntu desktop
with my chromebook and Win11 machines remotely. This is also broken
now. X11vnc server will not start on Wayland.
Finally, I have not been able to get Ubuntu's native desktop
share method to work with a native Win11 remote desktop connection. I
have dual monitors on both my Ubuntu machine and my local (same LAN)
Win11 machine. Yet, when I rdp into my Ubuntu 24.04 machine from the Win11 machine, only one of the two monitor wide desktop displays and it seems to be
completely unaware that there is another display (i.e. no horizontal
scrollbar, no ability to move over to the other display on the remote
machine). Of course, rdp works fine when I connect to my work Win11
laptop (via vpn, I get a full-width two monitor desktop).

These issues all appear to be the result of the move to Wayland by Ubuntu desktop. The ability to switch base to Xorg appears to be missing and/or undocumented at this time.
Is there a simple and functional drop-in replacement for Barrier and X11vnc on Ubuntu? Or an rdp server that communicates the whole desktop to the client computer over rdp?
I can't believe that I am the only person with this issue, but I have not found a viable solution that would work. I've been a Ubuntu desktop user since version 11 and I've spent quite a bit of effort getting my workflow to... Work. I'm not looking to spend a lot more time waiting or developing a solution to a system that worked well previously.
If there are no solutions that work with Wayland, is there a debian-based distro that still uses Xorg that you would recommend?
Unfortunately, I've seen a lot of angst out there. I'm not looking to poo-poo anybody's vision of the future, but I need to work now. Thanks in advance.

Human commentary: This experience was, unfortunately, horrible and frustrating for me. I like using a Linux OS because I feel I have more control over the system. This experience (having to completely re-install the OS and start from scratch) has taught me that others can undermine the foundation on which I build my environment and tools and in doing so, can force me to relearn things that I had relied on and  forgotten years ago. I can relate to those I see leaving Ubuntu. I hate to say it, but I just need things to work.

If your workflow requires X, you can sign into that in Ubuntu 24.04.  Once you get to the password screen, there is a gear in the lower right corner. If you click it, you get the option to sign in on X.

(I don't use 24.04, I just spun up a virtual machine to see if this option was still available. It seems like there are a lot of problems with this release, so you may still have issues. This answer addresses only signing in to X).

Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, the upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 didn't include that option! My login screen does not have the "gear in the corner" that everyone is referring to and I have been unable to get it to appear. In the process, i recently broke my desktop and now there are missing components to gnome and gnome won't respond to mouse clicks. I certainly agree with your assessment that there are a lot of problems with this release.

@BE-Bob Weird. Just to be clear, the "gear" is on the password screen, not the login screen.  Well, if you must use 24.04, my experiment showed that a clean install does have the "gear", so you could clean install and then load your backups. It sounds like your system is hopelessly broken anyway, so a clean install is probably in your future. Reading all this 24.04 stuff makes me really glad I switched to Debian for most of my boxes.

Thank you for your help. Ultimately, I did a clean install of Ubuntu 24.04.1 over the original install. This solved the problem and somehow defaulted to Xorg as the display system. This also added the "gear" to the password screen during login.
